# Security Risks associated with Thread.CurrentPrincipal.Identity.Name

Tags: c#, wcf, wcf-security

I am working on WCF application, where I want to store the file in the user-specific folder.
In order to get the current logged in user I am using:

**var identityName = Thread.CurrentPrincipal.Identity.Name;**

I wanted to understand any security threats associated with this.

Here is my code for Reference:

```
             private static string GetDirectoryPath()
                    {
                        var start = DateTime.Now;
                        LoggerWrapper.CMLogger.LogMessage("AssetController.GetDirectoryPath: START...", LoggerWrapper.CMLogger.CMLogLevel.Debug);
                        try
                        {
                            var directoryPathAppSetting =
                                System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ExportProjectPath"];
                            //Get Current User 
                            var identityName = Thread.CurrentPrincipal.Identity.Name;
                            var currentUser = identityName.Split(SplitDirectoryPath).Last().ToString();
                            var directoryPath = string.Format(directoryPathAppSetting, currentUser);

                            LoggerWrapper.CMLogger.LogMessage("AssetController.GetDirectoryPath END:", LoggerWrapper.CMLogger.CMLogLevel.Debug);
                            return directoryPath;
                        }
```

Comment: I suspect I could have some fun if my `Name` started with "..\" (which would likely involve my file being written to a folder you don't expect).

Comment: So @mjwills I thought this can't be right, so I checked and only the following characters are disallowed, ""/\[]:|<>+=;,?*%@".  Period and backslash are OK! (IDK if this can be changed by group policy).